# Jquery ajax sends multiple responses back in Chrome while in FF sends only one response

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, google-chrome

The problem is ,when there is a new message, instead of alert only one time, with Chrome, it alerts 5-8 times with the same value. In contrast, these codes work well with FF, it alerts only one time. How can I fix the codes to support Chrome. 
HTML:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('/restaurant/get_msg_notification',{},function(data){
        alert(data)
    })
}, 1000)
```

View:

```
def get_msg_notification(request):    
    while True:
        # check is there any new messages ?
        msg = Message.objects.filter(receiver = user, notify = False)
        if( len(msg)==0 and patient<5):
            time.sleep(5)
            patient+=1
        else:
            break
    if( len(msg) > 0):
        data = serializers.serialize('json', msg)
        msg.update(notify = True)
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("")
```

Comment: Now I try to delete 'patient' variable so it is not long polling at all. The method gives me a proper result(response only one time). However, without long polling, ajax needs to send a request every second which is expensive.

Comment: Found the great explanation of long polling and the solution from this link. http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Firefox seems to be the one not working properly. Try the following code instead:

```
def get_msg_notification(request):    
    while True:
        # check is there any new messages ?
        msg = Message.objects.filter(receiver = user, notify = False)
        if(patient < 5):
            time.sleep(5)
            patient+=1
        else:
            if (len(msg) != 0):
                msg.update(notify = True)
            break

    data = serializers.serialize('json', msg)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: I forgot to write if condition outside while loop into the question. Now I included that condition into the question already. By the way, why do you think FF doesn't work properly?